# List and List<?> in Java

Tags: java

What is the difference between `List` and `List<?>`? I know I can't add any element to the `List<?>`. I have a code:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
processList(myList);
processListGeneric(myList);

public static void processList(List myList) {
Iterator it = myList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
}

public static void processListGeneric(List<?> myList) {
    Iterator<?> it = myList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
        System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

The name of the two methods cannot be the same, because it causes compile time error. So is there any difference in these two approaches?

Comment: It does not compile because the two methods would have the same signature, since the generics (<>) are only used by the compiler to check against type at compile time.

Comment: You can add null to it. So don't say you cannot add anything to it :)

Comment: With `java.awt.List` using the second method, I don't think your class would compile... ;)

Answer (score 6):

Both do the same, but in second case compiler is informed that you really want a list with no type bounds and raises no warnings. If you are working with Java 5 or later you are encouraged to use second approach.

Comment: `List<?>` is *not* the same as `List<Object>`. As the OP pointed out, you can't add to `List<?>`s while it is of course perfectly possible to add to `List<Object>`s. Further, if a method takes a `List<?>` as an argument, it is legal to pass, e.g., a `List<String>` to it. A method that takes a `List<Object>` would not accept a `List<String>`.

Comment: @sepp2k Removed controversial part.

Comment: You're still claiming that "both do the same". The second version of the method will accept arguments that the first one does not. So the two versions of the method are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you can't add anything to a `List<?>`, since it's a List of an unknown type.

For example, you are prevented from doing this:

```
List<Integer> listOfInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<?> list = listOfInt;
list.add("hello?"); // Compile-time error
```

You can add anything you want to the base type `List` since the type of the list items is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

`List<?>` (pronounced "collection of unknown")is a collection whose element type matches anything. It's called a wildcard type for obvious reasons.
Refer to the following code

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("John");
String name = myList.get(0);
System.out.println(name); //print John
List<?> myListNew = myList;
myListNew.add("Sam");//Compile time error
String nameNew = myListNew.get(0);//Compile time error
Object newName = myListNew.get(0);
System.out.println(newName);//Prints John
```

Since we don't know what the element type of **myListNew** stands for, we cannot add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?, it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.

On the other hand, given a `List<?>`, we can call get() and make use of the result. The result type is an unknown type, but we always know that it is an object. It is therefore safe to assign the result of get() to a variable of type Object or pass it as a parameter where the type Object is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The second method uses generics (introduced in Java 5).

One important distinction is the `<?>` represents a single type, not any object like this:

```
List<? extends Object> myList
```

So you could say that using the first method (without the wildcard syntax) is more flexible, as you'd be able to add any object to your List. Although, you'll get a (compiler) warning that you declaration should be parameterized.

Using the `<?>` unbounded wildcard syntax will avoid the warning, but you're telling the compiler it could be a list of any type, instead of actually using generics to enforce type safety. You are strongly encouraged to use generics to assist you in making your application type safe.

If, for example, you know that the list should only ever contain String objects, declare it thus:

```
List<String> myList
```

Then you'll avoid unnecessary casting of use of the `instanceof` operator, etc.

Here's a brief tutorial on generics in Java, for your information:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

List is raw type and List< ?> is wildcard type. Take look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

Both of them behave same. Using parametrized notation you are just avoiding any warnings in Java5 and above. You cannot have both the syntax in same java file because due to type erasure compiled unit has two methods with exactly same signature in same class file and thus violating language rules.
Following is what you would be getting from compiler:

Method processList(List) has the same erasure processList(List) as another method in type ...

Answer (score 0):

Just writing `List` without a type parameter is deprecated, but otherwise the same as writing `List<Object>`. So the question becomes "What's the difference between `List<Object>` and `List<?>` and which one should I use?".

As you already know, you can't add (anything other than `null`) to a `List<?>`, so if you need to add to a list, you should use a `List<Object>` (or a more specific type where applicable, of course). On the other hand, a method that takes a `List<Object>`, only accepts `List<Object>`s and not any lists that contain a subclass of `Object`. That is, it would not accept a `List<String>`. If the method takes a `List<?>` however, it accepts any kind of list. So if you don't need to add to the list, you should use `List<?>` as it is more general.